# How to limit the Messages falling in search datarange only in GMailApp.search()

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using Google App Script to search for certain mail messages falling in between dateOld to datNew

However, GmailApp returning Threas with Messages (all messages in thread) even if one message meets the date creiteria mentioned above

How do i filter out messages falling in only my supplied dateRange ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, short of checking the messages after the search yourself. GmailApp uses the same search as Gmail and that's how it handles dates.

Comment: i dont understand ? if a thread has 1 message which falls in my date-range entire thread is returned ? There should be a way to filter !

Comment: This is the same behavior as search in the Gmail web UI. Yes, that's how it considers date searches. There is no filter option short of writing code to loop through the messages yourself and choose what you want.

Comment: To clarify even more, Gmail searches always search individual messages and always return the whole thread containing the matching messages. This is a fundamental design decision of Gmail search.

Comment: i understand it as a limitation/constraint with gmail api. but is there a workaround atleast ?

Comment: Yes, loop through the returned messages and keep only those you want.